# Killed by another player?

Tags: dark-souls

I play Dark Souls on the XBox 360 and enjoy the online features like giving advice or seeing the ghosts of other players to avoid their mistakes.

But yesterday I heard a strange sound, like some kind of announcement sound and then there was another player in my world. I didn't agree to it or something. I was in the undead church and this other player just ran towards me. He buffed himself or something like that. I could clearly see that it was not an NPC because sometimes he ran towards me, then waited a bit, turned around, ran around me. Then he just killed me with one blow of his sword.

He was all in flames and his sword was on flames, too. I know that there is no kind of NPC like this in the undead church so this must have been another player.

*Is it normal that other players can enter my world and kill me? Can I avoid PvP in Dark Souls?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, PVP is totally normal in Dark Souls.

**What happened** - you got [invaded](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Invaders).

You can only get invaded if:

1. You are in human form (non-hollow)
2. The section boss is still alive
3. You are online

So - If you don't want to get invaded by human players, stay hollow or go offline.

There are NPC invaders. These will invade even if you are offline (you still need to be in human form, though). They appear in the following locations:

- Depths - Kirk, knight of Throns
- Blighttown - Mildred the Maneater
- Painted - Xanthous King
- Tomb of the Giants - Paladin Leeroy
- Demon Ruins - Kirk (again)
- Lost Izalith - Kirk (AGAIN)
- Oolacile Townshipt - Marvellous Chester

Comment: Not only to you but the answers as well: I thought that invading another world means joining another player and defeating the section boss in co-op. I think I play Dark Souls for a reason so I will not avoid PvP. Now that I know than it can happen any time I can prepare better. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @Exa check also my link, it will give you some more information about PvP, good luck :D

Comment: @Exa - There are invasions (PVP) and there are summons (Coop). Rules to summon another player are not so different - if you want to summon: You need to be online, in human form and the section boss must still live.  If these requirements are met, you will see white soapstone markings on the ground (usually near the boss or bonfire). More info on coop is on the [wiki](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/co-op)

Answer (score 2):

You can go [on the Dark Souls Wiki](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/pvp) to get more information. Basically you can Invade other people's world from certain location in the world. You can do it [by using a Cracked Red Eye Orb](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/cracked-red-eye-orb) and **only** when you are human.

To avoid being invaded you have 2 solutions :

- Remain in hollow form
- Play offline

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that I already have some of those cracked red eye orbs :) Another question would be if I would join a player who has a similiar character level to mine or if I can appear next to a level 5 guy as well as a level 100 guy?

Comment: @Exa I dont know much about those mechanics sine I never invaded anyone and the only guy who invaded me fell into lava 10 sec later while trying to attack me (that was epic by the way)

Comment: @Exa - There is a handy [calculator](https://mpql.net/tools/dark-souls/) that shows you exactly which levels you can get.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! (@WizLiz Yeah, yesterday it was kind of epic too. A wall of flames running at me, killing me with one blow.)

Answer (score 1):

Other players entering your world and killing you (or you killing them) is by design. It happens when a player uses one of several items to invade another players world.

You can avoid it by disconnecting from the network, or (less practically) staying in one of the areas that do not allow multiplayer activity. These are:

- Undead Asylum
- Valley of Drakes
- Great Hollow
- Ash Lake

Answer (score 0):

It is totally normal to get invaded. The invading players can be a jack-in-the-box sometimes though. They could help you get to a certain part but right when you aren't looking they can run you through from behind resulting in all your progress together to be lost so be wary of them.